# Convert Cocoa timestamp in Python

Tags: python, cocoa, timestamp

I have a Cocoa timestamp (zero time of January 1st, 2001 00:00:00 UTC) that I need to convert in Python.  When I use the following code it assumes a Unix timestamp input.  Besides adding 31 years in seconds (Just under a billion seconds...) what's the best way to convert the time?

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("495759456")).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

The output for this line of code is '1985-09-16 16:12:03'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to be careful on when doing the conversion with the above solution, is to make sure that the Cocoa timestamp's unit is the same as the one you'd want in the unix timestamp. I've noticed that at many instance the cocoa timestamp is stored in nano seconds.

Unless you want your Unix timestamp to also be represented as nano seconds, make sure to do divide the cocoa timestamp by the appropriate number before conversion. e.g. Divide by 1000000000 to convert nano seconds to seconds etc...

[Source](https://www.thecodeship.com/general/converting-cocoa-unix-timestamp/)

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work for you:

```
from datetime import datetime

unix = datetime(1970, 1, 1)  # UTC
cocoa = datetime(2001, 1, 1)  # UTC

delta = cocoa - unix  # timedelta instance

timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(int("495759456")) + delta

print(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

I didn't specify timezone information for the two starts of time as they're in the same zone so I assume it shouldn't matter which is used when computing the difference.  For converting the timestamp string, you may need to adjust for your timezone if it's different than the one in which the string was generated.

The above code produces `2016-09-16 15:57:36`